# Java interfaces error for list<String> eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, interface

[image: what I need to implement]

```
package com.lab3;

public interface Student {

    long getStudentNumber();

    void setStudentNumber(long s);

    String getName();

    void setName(String s);

    List<String> getSchedule();

    void setSchedule(List<String> s);

}
```

The last two I get an error "list cannot be resolved into a type"

How to fix?

Comment: You need to import it... `import java.util.List`

Comment: You need to import it `import java.util.List;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you need to import the class. In Java, you need to import classes which are defined in a different package if you want to use them. The `List` interface is defined in `java.util`, so you need to import it. If you are using an IDE, you can over your mouse over the error and it will recommended fixes, one of those should be "import". If not, you can add the following line above you interface:

```
import java.util.List;
```